# Checkboxes RecyclerView Adapter checked condition kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, checkbox, android-recyclerview

I create a checkboxes adapter in a bottom sheet like this :

[image]

I need 3 conditions :

- the "CHECK ALL" checkbox can check all checkboxes in adapter, also can uncheck all.
- save all datas after check the "CHECK ALL" checkbox
- set checkbox *isChecked* condition from saved data when re-open the bottom sheet adapter.

in my **onBindViewHolder**, i do like

```
        holder.binding.checkbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(null)
        holder.binding.checkbox.isChecked = item.isChecked
        setCheckboxTextColor(item.isChecked, holder)

        holder.binding.checkbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener { buttonView, isChecked ->
            if (item.isChecked != isChecked) {
                setCheckboxTextColor(isChecked, holder)
                item.isChecked = isChecked

                val indexList = mutableListOf<Int>()
                listData.filter { it.id == item.id }.forEach {
                    it.isChecked = isChecked
                    indexList.add(listData.indexOf(it))
                    if (isChecked) {
                        datas.add(it)
                    } else {
                        datas.remove(it)
                    }
                }
                indexList.forEach {
                    notifyItemChanged(it)
                }
                onClick(datas)
            }
        }
```

It's ok for a single selection checkbox, but I can't set the checked condition for the checkbox. So what should I do for the "CHECK ALL" and set a checkbox state for the re-open condition ?

in addition for activity - bottom sheet - adapter codes :

```
     //activity
     binding.edittext.setOnClickListener {
         val dialog = ListBottomSheet("list-tools", id_location)
         dialog.show(childFragmentManager, "dialog")
         dialog.setOnclick(object : ListBottomSheet.OnSelectedString {
           override fun onItemSelected(data: List<ListCheckboxModel>, position: List<Int>) {
                    posJenis.clear()
                    posJenis.addAll(position)
                    datas.clear()
                    datas.addAll(data)
                    isLog("act::$datas")
                    binding.etJenisItem.setText("${position.size} terpilih")
                    dialog.dismiss()
                }
            })
        }

      //bottom sheet

    private val adapter by lazy(LazyThreadSafetyMode.NONE) {
        ListCheckboxAdapter(
            ::onClicked
        )
    }

    private var datas: MutableList<ListCheckboxModel> = ArrayList()
    private var selectedDatas: MutableList<ListCheckboxModel> = ArrayList()

             datas.clear()
             datas.add(ListCheckboxModel("0000", nama = "CHECK ALL", keterangan = "check semua", isChecked = false))
             datas.addAll(it)
             adapter.clear()
             adapter.insertAll(datas, selectedDatas)

    private fun onClicked(data: List<ListCheckboxModel>) {
        selectedDatas.clear()
        selectedDatas.addAll(data)
    }

    //adapter
class ListCheckboxAdapter(
    private val onClick: (List<ListCheckboxModel>) -> Unit
) : RecyclerView.Adapter<ListCheckboxAdapter.ViewHolder>() { ...

    private var datas: MutableList<ListCheckboxModel> = ArrayList()
    var listData: MutableList<ListCheckboxModel> = ArrayList()

    fun insertAll(
        data: List<ListCheckboxModel>,
        data2: List<ListCheckboxModel>
    ) {
        data.forEach {
            listData.add(it)
            notifyItemInserted(listData.size - 1)
        }
        datas.addAll(data2)
    }
```